# Bind UserControl with Object DataSource

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, sqldatasource, objectdatasource

I have a Multi Select CheckBox user control. I want to bind this control with an object data source or sql data source but I don't know how to pass sql or object data source to my user control and how can I bind my user control with it. This process has to be like we bind a DropDownList using SQLDataSource with in aspx page and no C# code.

Please tell me a method to pass my data source to user control and then bind user control according to that datasource.

Comment: Why did you tag c# then?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany by mistake. Removed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward, you can get everything from the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx). However, below is an example of the most common configuration:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ConnectionString="some connection string"
    SelectCommand="some SELECT statement"
    ID="mySqlDataSource"
    runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And if your SELECT statement has parameters, you can specify those with markup too.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ...>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="parmName"
            DefaultValue="some value"
            Type="String" />
        </asp:Parameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I know how to use sqldatasource. My actual problem is how to bind usercontrol with sqldqtqsource or objectdatasource. Please tel me know can I bind my user control with this sqldatasource.

Comment: @Nikhil, and what exactly do you mean by **bind**? Do you mean **bind** it so it can list that data or do you mean **bind** its value as a parameter?

Comment: I want that first case. I'll set sqldatasource id to my usercontrol and usercontrol will get data from sqldatasource and list all the result values.